# On Einstein's argument at the beginning of his PhD thesis

Tags: einstein, atomic-theory

In *Investigations on the theory of Brownian movement*, he says that osmosis holds for solute particles but not for Brownian ones, since they are too big to pass through a permeable membrane.

**So what? Why should this prevent such Brownian particles to exercise pressure?**

Later on, one reads

> But a different conception is reached from the standpoint of the molecular-kinetic theory of heat. According to this theory a dissolved molecule is differentiated from a suspended body *solely* by its dimensions

In my view, **this argument seems totally uncorrelated from the previous one**, even though in the paper they are contiguous. I don't understand the reasoning.

Comment: If the Brownian particle can not go through the membrane, then the membrane is indistinguishable from a sheet of steel. It has no influence on the other side, it does not interact with the other side. Since this is associated with the _size_ of the Brownian particle, it makes sense to contrast the second section using size as well.

Comment: Ok, but... what happens concretely? I mean... If I put a membrane, do suspended particles exert pressure (even if they're too big for the membrane) or not?